# Had been already given or had already been given. Both are correct?

Tags: meaning

The sentence : We had been already given three presents or We had already been given three presents. Can native speakers understand both sentences ? For Grammar,  which one is correct ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

**We had already been given** is the correct form. The other one doesn't sound natural. In general, in the passive voice, "already" is placed between "been" and past participle of varb.

If you also google "We had already been given" and  "We had been already given" you will see that there is a huge difference between the frequency of the above two expressions.

You may refer to the below links for more examples:

http://ab51.org/?p=1114

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-of-time-and-frequency/already

Answer (score 0):

**we had** is it self a pronoun and a verb. They’ll stick together. 
**been given** also stick together. Because been is a used with a past participle to form the passive mood.

**already** is an adverb, which generally will go before the verb [(see here for extra reading)](https://www.thoughtco.com/adverb-placement-in-english-1211117) but there are exemptions like your example, which it’d go after the verb.

Examples:

I already have one.

I had already had one.

When using the passive mood it goes after.